# phpMyAdmin tries to install Apache

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, phpmyadmin, hhvm

I'm playing up with installing new environments on my server, Nginx webserver in conjunction with HHVM.

I installed both, then came to MariaDB and installed it as well. I can confirm server's working by hitting IP address: *Welcome to nginx!*

I then needed to install a web-based client for managing databases. I know phpMyAdmin works with Apache and Litespeed very well but as I followed many articles regarding to installing phpMyAdmin beside Nginx, steps were almost the same.

But the problem is doing `apt-get install phpmyadmin` will install Apache too:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data dbconfig-common libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1
  libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libjs-codemirror
  libjs-jquery libjs-jquery-cookie libjs-jquery-event-drag
  libjs-jquery-metadata libjs-jquery-mousewheel libjs-jquery-tablesorter
  libjs-jquery-ui libjs-underscore php-gettext php5 php5-common php5-json
  php5-mcrypt php5-mysql
```

By confirming installation it will install and enable Apache modules:

```
[...]
Enabling module mpm_event.
Enabling module authz_core.
Enabling module authz_host.
Enabling module authn_core.
Enabling module auth_basic.
Enabling module access_compat.
Enabling module authn_file.
Enabling module authz_user.
Enabling module alias.
Enabling module dir.
Enabling module autoindex.
Enabling module env.
Enabling module mime.
Enabling module negotiation.
Enabling module setenvif.
Enabling module filter.
Enabling module deflate.
Enabling module status.
[...]
```

and then throwing an error that Apache couldn't get started:

```
* Starting web server apache2                                                              AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using vultr.guest. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 *
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
Setting up dbconfig-common (1.8.47+nmu1) ...
```

I'm migrating from Apache to Nginx that means I don't want Apache anymore! Is it a default behavior of phpMyAdmin? Anyway to run phpMyAdmin with the latest versions of Nginx and HHVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this behavior are the dependencies of `phpmyadmin` (at least in `Debian`, and I think it's quite similar in `Ubuntu`):

```
# apt-cache show phpmyadmin | grep Depends:
libapache2-mod-php5 | libapache2-mod-php5filter | php5-cgi | php5-fpm | php5, php5-mysql | php5-mysqli | php5-mysqlnd, php5-mcrypt, php5-json, perl, debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, libjs-sphinxdoc (>= 1.0), dbconfig-common, php-gettext, ucf (>= 0.28)

# apt-cache show libapache2-mod-php5 | grep Depends:
libbz2-1.0, libc6 (>= 2.15), libcomerr2 (>= 1.01), libdb5.3, libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2), libk5crypto3 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2), libkrb5-3 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2), libonig2 (>= 5.9.5), libpcre3 (>= 1:8.35), libqdbm14 (>= 1.8.74), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), libxml2 (>= 2.9.0), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), apache2-api-20120211, apache2 (>= 2.4), mime-support, php5-common (= 5.6.14+dfsg-0+deb8u1), php5-cli, php5-json, libmagic1, ucf, tzdata
```

Inside the second listing of required packages you'll find `apache2`, which will install this package. So, not that much magic involved.

If you install `phpmyadmin` like you did, you can't purge `apache2` afterwards. Doing so, will remove `phpmyadmin` as well, because the dependencies aren't satisfied anymore.

So...what to do, if you want to install `phpmyadmin`, but at the same time don't want to install `apache2`? Not that hard as well:

`phpmyadmin` depends on several packages providing the `php5` interpreter / libraries / modules. As there are several options, it's up to you to choose. You don't need all these packages, it's more like an "this package `OR` this package `OR` that one". (Note the `|` in the required package listing of `phpmyadmin`.)

So, you've to *first* install the needed `php5` packages which aren't connected to `apache2`, and *afterwards* install `phpmyadmin`:

```
# apt-get install php5-fpm
[...]
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   libonig2 libqdbm14 php5-common php5-fpm

# apt-get install phpmyadmin
[...]
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   dbconfig-common libltdl7 libmcrypt4 libmysqlclient18 mysql-common php5-mcrypt php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```

If you've additional question or are in need of further help, please let me know.

**Edit**: Regarding your comment about other web based database management systems: You could have a look at [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/en/). Quoting the project website (can't judge this for myself):

> Replace phpMyAdmin with Adminer and you will get a tidier user interface, better support for MySQL features, higher performance and more security.

There are `Ubuntu` packages [available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=adminer&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) as well.

Comment: Thank you for all explanations. Is Adminer Nginx friendly? I didn't find related things about it.

Comment: @rev Glad that it helped. Not sure what you mean by "Nginx friendly". In the end it's just php, so yeah, nginx will serve you well. (Note: I'm not really into the php world, and especially I've never used or worked with `HHVM`. So if you want to use `HHVM`, and can't provide any insight into this topic.)

Comment: Or just install phpmyadmin from tarball.

Answer (score 2):

I'm kinda using your same stack (so no apache involve). What i like to use is

```
apt-get --no-install-recommends install phpmyadmin
```

And this will only install phpmyadmin withou apache

Comment: I wasn't aware of existence of that option. Thanks.